# Nested Dictionaries within a Dictionary Structure in Python, Would like to output in a specific manner

Tags: python, file, dictionary, nested, output

I have done analysis around stack overflow for an answer to this but it feels a bit specific, happy to go to your links if you suggest them.

**A. I've got a dictionary holding a bunch of dictionaries in this format:**

```
Key  :  {Nested_Key: Nested_Value}

Key = Document ID, Data Type is String
Nested Key = Token ID, Data Type is Integer
Nested Value = Count of Token ID, Data Type is Integer
```

Example:

```
d = { '441' : {201:1, 220:1, 232:1, ..., 23231:4}, 
      '4452' : {203:43, 2202: 45} }
```

**B: I'd like to be able to output them into a text file in this format:**

```
document_(key), nested_key:nested value, nested_key:nested value \n
document_(key+1), nested_key:nested value, nested_key: nested value \n
```

I'm able to get fairly close to what I want using this code:

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    for key, token in dict.items():
        f.write('doc%s,%s\n' % (key, token))
```

But as you would expect it outputs the nested key and nested value in its dictionary

> doc_441,{201: 1, 220: 1, 232: 1, 240: 1, 241: 1, 242: 1, 243: 1, 245:
>   1, 246: 1, 250: 1, 255: 1, 260: 1, 271: 1, 493: 1, 494: 1, 540: 1,
>   608: 1, 609: 1, 610: 1, 611: 1, 612: 1, 613: 1, 614: 1, 835: 1, 836:
>   1, 965: 1, 966: 1, 967: 1, 986: 1, 1291: 1, 1292: 1, 1734: 1, 1735: 1,
>   1736: 1, 1748: 1, 1749: 1, 1762: 1, 1763: 1, 1818: 1, 1819: 1, 1820:
>   1, 1821: 1, 1822: 1, 1875: 1, 1881: 1, 1882: 1, 1883: 1, 1890: 1,
>   1891: 1, 1941: 1, 1947: 1, 1948: 1}
>
> doc_577,{201: 1, 205: 1, 217: 1, 232: 1, 233: 1, 235: 1, 236: 1, 237:
>   1, 238: 1, 241: 1, 242: 1, 243: 1, 244: 1, 245: 1, 246: 1, 247: 1,
>   248: 1, 249: 1, 250: 1, 251: 1, 280: 1, 448: 1, 493: 1, 494: 1, 537:
>   1, 540: 1, 571: 1, 572: 1, 573: 1, 574: 1, 575: 1, 669: 1, 670: 1,
>   671: 1, 672: 1, 673: 1, 674: 1, 675: 1, 690: 1, 731: 1, 732: 1, 733:
>   1, 734: 1, 735: 1, 736: 1, 770: 1, 771: 1, 772: 1, 773: 1, 777: 1,
>   947: 1, 948: 1, 949: 1, 950: 1}

I've tried some ridiculously convoluted code to try and cajole the code into what I want but this one only outputs the last line in the nested dictionary's nested key: nested token

```
combined_file_content = ""

# For Key, Token pair in dict
for key, token in dict.items():
    for nest_key, nest_token in iter(token.items()):
        file_content = ""
        # This side works
        int_id = ""
        # Set int_id = doc_(key).txt,
        int_id = "doc_" + '(' + key + ')' + '.txt' + ','

        # Then for token dictionary,
        # For nested key, nested token pair in token dictionary
        # Set int_value = key:value
        int_value = ""
        nested_key = nest_key
        nested_token = nest_token

        int_value += (str(nested_key) + ":" + str(nested_token))
        #print(str(nested_key) + ":" + str(nested_token))

        combined_nest = int_id + int_value + "\n"
        file_content += combined_nest
    combined_file_content += file_content
```

Output: `docresume_(441).txt,4334:1\nresume_(577).txt,4344:1\ndoc_(220).txt,4305:1\n`

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried pprint?

Comment: The last bunch of code works when the python print function is used with it but I'm trying to output them into a file, unless one can use print to do that? I'm not aware.

Comment: So for a document_key you want to print all the nested key, values in one line?

Comment: If the way the function prints your output is what you want you can direct the output to a file by running it like this: `python yourcode.py > yourfile.txt`

Comment: Yes specifically I would like to output them from my nested dictionary structure to a text file in the following format: document_key1, nested_key:nested_value, nested_key:nested_value\n document_key2, nested_key:nested_value, nested_key:nested_value\n

Comment: Otherwise you can always use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, this should do it:

```
d = {'doc_441' :{201: 1, 220: 1, 232: 1, 240: 1, 241: 1, 242: 1, 243: 1, 245: 1, 246: 1, 250: 1, 255: 1, 260: 1, 271: 1, 493: 1, 494: 1, 540: 1, 608: 1, 609: 1, 610: 1, 611: 1, 612: 1, 613: 1, 614: 1, 835: 1, 836: 1, 965: 1, 966: 1, 967: 1, 986: 1, 1291: 1, 1292: 1, 1734: 1, 1735: 1, 1736: 1, 1748: 1, 1749: 1, 1762: 1, 1763: 1, 1818: 1, 1819: 1, 1820: 1, 1821: 1, 1822: 1, 1875: 1, 1881: 1, 1882: 1, 1883: 1, 1890: 1, 1891: 1, 1941: 1, 1947: 1, 1948: 1},
'doc_577' : {201: 1, 205: 1, 217: 1, 232: 1, 233: 1, 235: 1, 236: 1, 237: 1, 238: 1, 241: 1, 242: 1, 243: 1, 244: 1, 245: 1, 246: 1, 247: 1, 248: 1, 249: 1, 250: 1, 251: 1, 280: 1, 448: 1, 493: 1, 494: 1, 537: 1, 540: 1, 571: 1, 572: 1, 573: 1, 574: 1, 575: 1, 669: 1, 670: 1, 671: 1, 672: 1, 673: 1, 674: 1, 675: 1, 690: 1, 731: 1, 732: 1, 733: 1, 734: 1, 735: 1, 736: 1, 770: 1, 771: 1, 772: 1, 773: 1, 777: 1, 947: 1, 948: 1, 949: 1, 950: 1}}


combined_file_content = ""
# For Key, Token pair in dict
for key, token in d.items():
    file_content = ""
    int_id = "doc_" + '(' + key + ')' + '.txt' + ','
    for nest_key, nest_token in iter(token.items()):

        # Then for token dictionary,
        # For nested key, nested token pair in token dictionary
        # Set int_value = key:value
        int_value = ""
        nested_key = nest_key
        nested_token = nest_token

        int_value += (str(nested_key) + ":" + str(nested_token))
        file_content += int_value
    combined_file_content += int_id + file_content + "\n"
print(combined_file_content)
```

**Output**

```
doc_(doc_441).txt,260:11948:11291:11292:1271:11941:11818:11819:1540:11821:11822:11947:11734:11891:11820:11735:11890:1835:1836:1965:1966:1967:11736:1201:11875:11882:1610:1611:11748:11749:11881:1986:11883:1220:1608:1609:11762:11763:1612:1613:1614:1232:1493:1494:1240:1241:1242:1243:1245:1246:1250:1255:1
doc_(doc_577).txt,770:1771:1772:1773:1777:1237:1238:1280:1537:1540:1669:1670:1671:1672:1673:1674:1675:1690:1947:1948:1949:1950:1571:1572:1573:1574:1575:1448:1201:1205:1217:1731:1732:1733:1734:1735:1736:1232:1233:1235:1236:1493:1494:1241:1242:1243:1244:1245:1246:1247:1248:1249:1250:1251:1
```

As a side note avoid calling dictionaries `dict`, the name dict is already define as function for creating dictionaries. A simpler alternative to the code above is the following:

```
d = {'doc_441': {201: 1, 220: 1},
     'doc_577': {201: 1, 205: 1}}


def get_line(d):
    return ",".join('{}:{}'.format(nest_key, nest_token) for nest_key, nest_token in d.items())


# For Key, Token pair in dict
combined_file_content = '\n'.join("doc_({}).txt".format(key) + "," + get_line(token) for key, token in d.items())
print(combined_file_content)
```

**Output**

```
doc_(doc_441).txt,201:1,220:1
doc_(doc_577).txt,201:1,205:1
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, still very new to working with nested dictionaries, thanks to you I can finally rest for the day. Much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

That's hopefully what you want:

```
lines = ""
for k, v in d.items():
    lines += "document_({})".format(k)
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        lines = ", ".join([line, "{}:{}".format(k2,v2)])
    lines += "\n"
print(lines)
```

*Test:*

Using the input dictionary:

```
d = { '441' : {201:1, 220:1, 232:1, 23231:4},
  '4452' : {203:43, 2202: 45} }
```

the output becomes:

```
>>> document_(441), 201:1, 220:1, 232:1, 23231:4
>>> document_(4452), 203:43, 2202:45
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wanted, although this is a quick and dirty method it gives an output similar to your example

**code to write to the file**

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    for k in d:
        f.write("doc_({}), {}\n".format(k,str(d[k])[1:-1]))
```

**code to print the file contents**

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

**output of the code**

```
doc_(441), 201: 1, 220: 1, 232: 1, 23231: 4
doc_(4452), 203: 43, 2202: 45
```